# Linux : transform blocks of X lines string into 1 line string

Tags: linux, string, file, shell, parsing

I have in my PHP file this string :

```
$sql  = "SELECT p.pac_rut a, ";
$sql .= "       p.pac_dig b, ";
$sql .= "       p.pac_apepat c, ";
$sql .= "       p.pac_apemat d, ";
$sql .= "       p.pac_nombre e, ";
$sql .= "       to_char(p.pac_fecha_nac,'dd/mm/yyyy') as f, ";
$sql .= "       (to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')-to_char(p.pac_fecha_nac,'yyyy')) as g, ";
$sql .= "       p.sex_cod h ";
$sql .= "FROM   mytable ";
$sql .= "WHERE p.pac_rut=$rut";
```

And `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | sed 's/";  $sql .= "//g' | sed 's/  //g' | sed 's/=\$/=:/g'` gives me the result ok like : `$sql= "SELECT p.pac_rut a,p.pac_dig b,p.pac_apepat c,p.pac_apemat d,p.pac_nombre e,to_char(p.pac_fecha_nac,'dd/mm/yyyy') as f,(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')-to_char(p.pac_fecha_nac,'yyyy')) as g,p.sex_cod h FROM salud.pacientes p WHERE p.pac_rut=:rut";`
But if a have 2 (or more) blocks of sql queries, i need a function which can build 2 (or more) queries sql on 2 (or more) lines.
For ejample, i have :

```
$sql  = "SELECT p.pac_rut a ";
$sql .= "FROM   mytable ";
$sql .= "WHERE p.pac_rut=$rut";
```

and

```
$sql2  = "SELECT p.pac_rut a ";
$sql2 .= "FROM   mytable ";
$sql2 .= "WHERE p.pac_rut=$rut";
```

in the same file, i need this result :

```
$sql  = "SELECT p.pac_rut a FROM   mytable WHERE p.pac_rut=$rut";
$sql2  = "SELECT p.pac_rut a FROM   mytable WHERE p.pac_rut=$rut";
```

How can i do that with awk or sed or other linux tool ?

Comment: But what's the problem with multiline assignment?

Comment: The problem is that i want to use sed or awk to replace some php variables.